# SQL Converting Column type from float to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy, sql-types

I'm trying to change the datatype in a column in a table from `Float` (null) to `Varchar(25)` (null). The largest float in the current data is 12 digits, but more digits may have to be added in the future, hence `varchar(25)`.

The current data in the column is phone numbers. The change must be made to allow for preceding zeros.

However, I'm having some difficulties doing this.

I've tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer 
ALTER COLUMN Phonenumber varchar(25)
```

This does not give me the desired result.

For instance `1549779498` becomes `1.54978e+009`

Then I've tried something in the lines of this:

- Creating a new (temporary) column `PhonenumberVarchar`
- Converting and copying the data from one column to another
- Deleting the old column
- Renaming the new column to the old name

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer 
ADD PhonenumberVarchar varchar(25)

UPDATE Customer 
SET PhonenumberVarchar = STR(Phonenumber, 12, 0)

ALTER TABLE Customer 
DROP COLUMN Phonenumber

EXEC sp_rename 'Customer.PhonenumberVarchar', 'Phonenumber', 'COLUMN'
```

This doesn't work either:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

And now it's late and my head hurts...

Can anyone help?

NOTE:

The table is rather large, some 1.5 million rows, so performance can be an issue.

Using SQL Server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix this by going through a `decimal` first:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER COLUMN Phonenumber decimal(25, 0);
ALTER TABLE Customer ALTER COLUMN Phonenumber varchar(25);
```

You get the same behavior when using `cast()`:

```
select cast(cast(1549779498 as float) as varchar(255))
```

So the fix is illustrated by:

```
select cast(cast(cast(1549779498 as float) as decimal(25)) as varchar(255))
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) for `alter table alter column` explicitly references `cast()`:

> Some data type changes may cause a change in the data. For example,
>   changing an nchar or nvarchar column to char or varchar may cause the
>   conversion of extended characters. For more information, **see CAST
>   and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)**. Reducing the precision or scale of a
>   column may cause data truncation.

EDIT:

After you load the data, I would suggest that you also add a check constraint:

```
check (PhoneNumber not like '%[^0-9]%')
```

This will ensure that numbers -- and only numbers -- remain in the column in the future.

Comment: This seems to work. So if I understand correctly the trick with the decimal conversion first is to make sure the rounding errors which I got using nvarchar directly are eliminated?

Comment: @user2110298 . . . Yes, although I'm not sure they are exactly rounding errors.  The representation used for the conversion is not what you want, and this is a relatively simple way around that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Direct float to varchar conversions can be tricky. Merely altering column data type wont be sufficient.

STEP 1: Take backup of your data table.

```
SELECT * INTO Customer_Backup FROM Customer
```

STEP 2: Drop and Create your original data table using SQL Server Scripts // OR // DROP and Alter the data type of the column

```
ALTER TABLE Customer 
ALTER COLUMN Phonenumber varchar(25)
```

STEP 3: In you scenario, since phone numbers don't have decimal data values in the float column, we can convert it first to int and then to varchar like below

```
INSERT into Customer (Phonenumber) 
SELECT convert (varchar(25), convert(int, [Phonenumber])) as [Phonenumber]
FROM Customer_Backup
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE Customer  ADD PhonenumberVarchar  VARCHAR(25)

GO

UPDATE Customer  SET PhonenumberVarchar  = str  (Phonenumber,12,0)

ALTER TABLE Phonenumber  ALTER COLUMN Phonenumber  VARCHAR(25)

UPDATE Customer  SET Phonenumber = PhonenumberVarchar 

ALTER TABLE Customer  DROP COLUMN PhonenumberVarchar
```

Comment: Using this code still gets the described error in the original post.